# Google Api Client Php - mkdir():Permission denied

Tags: php, mkdir, google-api-php-client, permission-denied

Using google api client for php to fetch some data, I have encountered the following error and I can't seem to find any working solution so far.

```
mkdir(): Permission denied
$storageDir = $this->path . '/' . substr(md5($file), 0, 2);
    if ($forWrite && ! is_dir($storageDir)) {
      if (! mkdir($storageDir, 0755, true)) {
        throw new Google_Cache_Exception("Could not create storage directory: $storageDir");
      }
```

I checked the permissions, users and groups. Everything is fine but I can't figure what's the problem.
Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved the problem by replacing `$this->path` with `storage_path()`