# Unable to connect to datastore via local php instance

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-api-php-client

I am trying to follow the guide at https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2013/12/23/getting-started-with-the-cloud-datastore-on-php-app-engine/ and I am up to the part of running the initial "datastore_connect" query

It works when I deploy remotely, but when I run locally I get this error in the browser:

> Warning: mkdir(): Permission denied in
>   Y:\UMBRELLA\SOCIALIBS\GAE\socialibs\php-libs\external\google-api-php-client-master\src\Google\Cache\File.php
>   on line 140

And looking at the logs I get:

> INFO     2015-01-27 11:14:01,859 module.py:718] default: "GET
>   /datastore_connect HTTP/1.1" 200 232

Note that the value of **$storageDir** when echo'd out is

> C:\WINDOWS/Google_Client/cb

Also, I realize this is possibly duplicate of [Google Api Client Php - mkdir():Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27088858/google-api-client-php-mkdirpermission-denied) but the answer there did not work for me and I'm not sure if the permission warning is the actual culprit anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php code line raising the error is coming from the getCacheDir method in the Google PHP library :

```
  if (! mkdir($storageDir, 0755, true)) {
```

It is related to the Cache directory, not to the Datastore itself.
You will need to apply to this directory at least this access permission (0755, linux representation : drwxr-xr-x) which allow a read/executable access for users and write/read/executable access for owner

Comment: I am no longer using PHP to access the Datastore, switched to Go so can't test, but assuming you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't the answer you are particularly looking for but..

I've been in your same position and I kinda gave up following that tutorial. I came across [Tom Walder's Google Datastore Library for PHP](https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds) and it is pretty amazing.

I highly suggest you check it out. I'm using it pretty full fledged in my application.